# Can't install SSRS 2008 R2 default instance

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 that had Reporting Services included and uninstalled. Default Instance.  I now need to add Reporting Services to the installation and I am getting an "Instance Name in use" when I try to install the default instance.  A named instance will not work in this case.

I checked the following registry location for any keys and it just has the "SQL" folder.  No "RS" folder.

HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\

So what I am really trying to figure out is where the installer is looking to see if the default instance already exists becasue that was obviously not cleaned up correctly on the uninstall.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the Registry Key (with similar name):

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.MSSQLSERVER`

and the folder:

`%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.MSSQLSERVER`